# Why does PathMatcher doesn't match path?

Tags: java, path, match, nio, glob

I research glob patterns.

I wrote simple example:

```
PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:D:\\folder1\\folder2\\**");
boolean isMatches  = matcher.matches(Paths.get("D:\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3"));
System.out.println(isMatches);
```

This code returns `false`.

If I use  one star in pattern -  I see same result.

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `\\\\` in path expression, to escape directory and reg expression

```
PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:D:\\\\dev\\\\server\\\\**");
boolean isMatches  = matcher.matches(Paths.get("D:\\dev\\server\\web"));
System.out.println(isMatches);
```

Comment: Oh, interesting) but 4 slashes looks awful)

Comment: **PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:D:/folder1/folder2/*");** this variant works too

Comment: @gstackoverflow good point your comment and it works too. Using `\\\\\` is reg exp way :)