# Glob Syntax not working for Windows PathMatcher

Tags: java, glob

For whatever reason, I can't seem to get a glob syntax path matcher to match any files.

I've simplified my code down to the following method:

```
public static void match() throws IOException {

        String startingLocation = "C:\\";

        PathMatcher pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:*");

        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(startingLocation), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path,
                    BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                if (pathMatcher.matches(path)) {
                    System.out.println(path);
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc)
                    throws IOException {
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }
```

My understanding is that that method should list out all of the files on my C drive. However, it does not print out a single file.

Interestingly enough, if I run the same thing with "regex:.*" instead of "glob:*", it does seem to be listing all of the files on my C drive.

I could go through the effort of converting my glob expression into a regex, but I'd really rather not.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?

Note that I am running on a Windows 7 machine with Java 8

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher%28java.lang.String%29) it would seem as though your glob expression should resemble `"glob:C:\\**"`.

Comment: It didn't work with "glob:C:\\\**" either.

Comment: Did you try `"glob:C:\\\\**"`? The javadoc states: *"note that the backslash is escaped; as a string literal in the Java Language the pattern would be `"C:\\\\*"`"*

Comment: ^ with regard to that comment, can you refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/25260067/1743880?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher(java.lang.String)) carefully.

If you want to print out all files of the `C:` drive,
change the pattern to `glob:**` or `glob:C:\\\\**` (as written in the javadoc).

Note also that `Files.walkFileTree` matches only files.

Comment: I think it needs to be `glob:C:\\\\**`.

Comment: Yes, so do I. (and just tested). `glob:**` did work though and printed the files under the C drive.

Comment: Thanks @JonnyHenly, you were right (also written in the javadoc)

Comment: Just to make it still maybe a bit clearer (I didn't understand it at first): Backslashes as path separators in the glob ALWAYS need to be escaped. If constructing the glob from String literals, this results in 4 slashes for one path separator.